# How do I add a line break to a 'div' using inner HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to add a line break using inner HTML. My code so far is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "hello";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += linebreakhere;
```

I've been searching, and is there a way to add like a <b> like the above?

Comment: Either pass <br/> in string or add CSS block property to element so that element goes to next line

Comment: That code is _inefficient_. Re-querying the DOM for getting the same element and modifying `innerHTML` , the worst way of appending elements.

Comment: Re "`<b>`": Do you mean "`<br>`"?

Answer (score 7):

You do this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "hello";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you can achieve the line break using `innerHtml`

Example 1:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello <br/> World";
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Example 2:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<pre>" + "Hello" + "\n" + "World"+ "</pre>";
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```